# drawToBitmap Method converting System::Windows::Forms::Control::DrawToBitmap to System::Drawing::Rectangle

Tags: c++, visual-studio, methods

I'm trying to print a datagridview by drawing to bitmap using visual studio 2008 C++ Windows Forms Application, however I'm having trouble converting the 2 types mentioned in the title. This is the method being called:

```
private:
   void printDocument1_PrintPage(System::Object ^ sender,
      System::Drawing::Printing::PrintPageEventArgs ^ e)
   {
      Bitmap^ bm = gcnew Bitmap(this->dataGridView1->Width, this->dataGridView1->Height);
            this->dataGridView1->DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, this->dataGridView1->Width, this->dataGridView1->Height));
            e->Graphics->DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);
   }
System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        printDialog1->ShowDialog();
        printDocument1->Print();
    }
```

However upon compiling the code I'm getting this error:

```
error C2664: 'System::Windows::Forms::Control::DrawToBitmap' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'System::Drawing::Rectangle *' to 'System::Drawing::Rectangle'
```

I'm clueless. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Rectangle is a value type.  Just remove *new*.

Comment: Removing new was also helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't the `new Rectangle(...)` code be `gcnew Rectangle(...)`? Remember that in Managed C++, `new` is NOT the same as `gcnew`.

Comment: I fixed that, but the error still appears:

error C2664: 'System::Windows::Forms::Control::DrawToBitmap' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'System::Drawing::Rectangle ^' to 'System::Drawing::Rectangle'

Comment: I'd create the `Rectangle` outside like so:

`Rectangle myRect; myRect.X=0; myRect.Y=0; myRect.Width=this->dataGridView1->Width; myRect.Height=this->dataGridView1->Height;`

You could also redo the code inline using `Rectangle::FromLTRB(...)` since the static method returns a value type (which `Rectangle` is).

Apparently in Managed C++, you have to watch for where value types are explicitly needed vs handles (`^`) to reference types.

Comment: Also, just try deferencing the handle of the new `Rectangle`: `*gcnew Rectangle(...)`.

Comment: That would be rather more complicated as it is, I've tried that but it just shows lots more errors than before. I'd rather find out what's wrong with the current.

Comment: Yes I added an asterisk after gcnew Rectangle. That worked. Any idea how to center my table now? It works but everything is in the top left corner. I want my tab to be in the center of the page.

Comment: That's a separate question. :)